# Sharing EventLoopGroup between client and server bootstraps

Tags: java, netty

I have an application that both acts as a UDP server and as a TCP client. Therefore, I create two `Bootstrap`s to set up Netty.

Is it a good idea to share the same `EventLoopGroup` between the two `Bootstrap`s?

It would mean that the same thread pool will be used to:

- Receive/reply to UDP datagrams
- Receiving TCP data

(Sending TCP data will be done by my application's threads.)

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a good idea and yes the threads will be used for udp and tcp.